# php change rows color with same value

Tags: php

I have a page which displays some data imported in MySQL database from Excel file
[image]

I want to change background color of rows with same values (grouped) on col "Billing Doc" like this picture:

[image]

Here is a part of my php code:

```
<form action="uploadExcel.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type= "submit" value ="Upload" >
    </div>
</form>
<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Billing Doc</th>
            <th>Invoice Date</th>
            <th>Ordered Parts</th>
            <th>Shipped Parts</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>F</th>
            <th>G</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Delivery No</th>
            <th>D/O Creation Date</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>P/O No</th>
            <th>Ship-to</th>
            <th>Tracking No</th>
            <th>Obs</th>
        </tr>
<?php
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    if (substr( $row->tracking_no, 0, 3 ) === "534") {
        $row->tracking_no = "<a href='http://www.dhl.be/en/express/tracking.html?pageToInclude=RESULTS&AWB=$row->tracking_no&type=fasttrack' title='DHL'>$row->tracking_no</a>";
    }
    if (substr( $row->tracking_no, 0, 3 ) === "730") {
        $row->tracking_no = "<a href='http://www.tnt.com/webtracker/tracker.do?navigation=1&respLang=en&respCountry=gb&cons=$row->tracking_no' title='TNT'>$row->tracking_no</a>";
    }
    $colour = '';
    echo '
        <tr style="background-color:' .$colour. '">
            <td>' . $row->id_factura . '</td>
            <td>' . $row->billing_doc . '</td>
            <td>' . $row->invoice_date . '</td>
            <td>' . $row->ordered_parts . '</td>
            <td>' . $row->shipped_parts . '</td>
            <td>' . $row->qty . '</td>
            <td>' . number_format($row->F, 2) . '</td>
            <td>' . number_format($row->G, 2) . '</td>
            <td>' . number_format($row->amount, 2) . '</td>
            <td>' . $row->delivery_no . '</td>
            <td>' . $row->d_o_creation_date . '</td>
            <td>' . $row->description . '</td>
            <td>' . $row->po_no . '</td>
            <td>' . $row->ship_to . '</td>
            <td>' . $row->tracking_no . '</td>
            <td>' . $row->obs . '</td>
        </tr>
    ';
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the only variable to consider is Billing Doc, if so, inside your while loop use an array to store the billing id as a key and then check every value to see if the key already exists then print the color you want to:

```
$billing_docs = [];

while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {

  echo '<tr style="background-color:' . (array_key_exists($row->id_factura, $billing_docs) ? '#666' : '#DDD') . '">...';
  $billing_docs[$row->id_factura] = '';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working.

<tr  style="background-color:' .(array_key_exists($row->billing_doc, $billing_docs) ? '#666' : '#DDD'). '">

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a variable with the first `billing_doc` value: `$billing = $row->billing_doc` and use an `if else` to echo the same color row if the `$billing_doc` value is the same.  The `else` would declare the new color variable and echo rows of that color.